# *Checklist* app for iPhone (pre-flight checklist, surgical safety checklist, etc)

Tags: iphone-app

There's a *lot* of task-list apps but what I want is a variant that's much harder to find. Basically, I want a 'checklist app'. I want to be able to create checklists, which should be pretty much just like any other list of tasks in any other task app. The difference tho, is that I want to be able to create 'instances' of any of the checklists, and track which of the tasks I marked completed for that instance.

Some example checklists:

- Items to set out to ride my bicycle to work.
- [Pre-flight tasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-flight_checklist) for flying an airplane.
- The [Surgical Safety Checklist](http://www.safesurg.org/uploads/1/0/9/0/1090835/surgical_safety_checklist_production.pdf)

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a program like this (web or Windows), and I don't want Trello. Did you happen to find anything else?

Comment: @RamRachum – I haven't found anything else but [this Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS543US543&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=iphone%20app%20checklist%20templates) might reference something more to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

## Trello

[Trello](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Ftrello-organize-anything%2Fid461504587%3Fmt%3D8&ei=zYi6VOWACcOagwSnpoSoAQ&usg=AFQjCNHgy25mC4NqKQdOHtYl3cooACQWBA&sig2=-id8hbjCauFKjuKyVnYMsg&bvm=bv.83829542,d.eXY) can do this. Here's some simple steps to do what I outlined in my question:

#### Setup a New Checklist Template

1. [Create a new 'board'](http://help.trello.com/article/719-adding-your-first-board) named, say, "Surgeries".
2. Add a 'list' to your checklists board for your checklist templates, named, say, "Templates".
3. Add a 'card' in the *Templates* list for your checklist, named, say, "Surgical Safety Checklist".
4. Click on the card you added to see the card details and then click on the "Checklist" button under the "Add" button list (on the right of the card details).
5. Enter an appropriate title for the new checklist, or just use the default "Checklist".
6. Click the green "Add" button to create the checklist.

#### Creating a New Instance of a Checklist from a Template

1. Add a new card to a list in your board, e.g. a card with the title "2015-01-17 - Left foot amputation of John Doe".
2. Click on the card you added and then click on the "Checklist" button under the "Add" button list.
3. Enter an appropriate title or just use the default "Checklist".
4. In the "Copy Items From..." dropdown, pick the relevant card and checklist that you wish to use as your template.

Another, perhaps easier, way:

1. Click on the appropriate template card to see the card details.
2. Click on the "Copy" button under the "Actions" list (on the right of the card details).
3. Edit the "Title", make sure you keep the checklists, and select the "Board", "List", and "Position" you want to the new copy to have.
4. Click the green "Create Card" button.

One advantage of the second set of steps is that copying a card can copy more than just a single checklist, e.g. pertinent info in the card "Description".

#### Pros and Cons

Pros

- Not only is there an iPhone app but there's an iPad app, and the [webapp](https://trello.com) is wonderful too.
- Trello is great for lots of other stuff.

Cons

- You can't currently edit cards offline. You can add new cards but that only lets you enter a title. You can view already-created cards and add comments and attachments tho.

#### Notes

I'd highly suggest that you name any checklist template cards with an '@' as the first character, e.g. "@Surgery template" (or "@Limb amputation template"), so that that card will be listed first in the dropdown that shows existing cards and their checklists (when creating a new checklist in another card).

Instead of creating multiple cards, one for each template, you could create a single card with all of the checklist templates. When you create a new checklist in a new card you can pick one of any number of existing checklists in another card.

Answer (score 0):

## Habitica

[Habitica](https://habitica.com) is a nice task app and you can add a checklist to some tasks.

Habitica has three types of 'tasks': habits, dailies, and to-do-s. For a checklist that you'd like to use repeatedly, the daily task type is the best fit as you can't add a checklist to a habit and to-do-s can't be easily copied [and you'd also probably want to copy the to-do *before* marking it completed, which is a little awkward].

The iPhone app is great, the website is pretty great too, and if your checklist(s) are things that you need or want to do on a regular schedule, then Habitica is probably a good fit.

One significant drawback tho is that a daily task in Habitica can only be completed once per day so they aren't a good fit for anything you might need to do more than once a day.

Answer (score 0):

## GitLab

[GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) is, among other things, a source control (Git) host (for software code) and an issue tracker. Issues are pretty useful for keeping track of small-ish 'projects' (i.e. collection of related tasks) like fixing a bug in a program or adding a new feature to a program. They're also pretty useful for anything for which you'd want to use a checklist.

Checklists can be added to a comment on the issue or to the issue's description. You'll probably want to do the latter in almost all cases.

To be able to re-use a checklist, you should create an issue [description template](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/description_templates.md). Then, when you want to create a new 'instance' of the checklist, you'll create a new issue and pick the description template with the relevant or desired checklist. You can then mark individual items in the checklist completed as well a 'close' (i.e. 'mark completed') the entire issue itself.

You should be able to use the gitlab.com website on an iPhone and there may also be a native third-party iOS app that supports description templates; see this page for possibilities:

- [Applications Supporting GitLab | GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/applications/)

The biggest drawbacks to using GitLab are probably all related to it being aimed at people that work with or on computer software. GitLab is based on [Git](https://git-scm.com/) source control software that's considered somewhat hard to use, even for software professionals. You can almost certainly get away with not using Git directly – you should be able to edit the necessary files directly from the GitLab website. But the need to edit files, and the probably confusion surrounding how to do that for people that *aren't* software professionals, may be a significant barrier to this as a general solution for most people.